# Generate a multicolumn table using docxtpl

Tags: python-3.x, ms-word

I have a series of data (in 2-dimensional list 'CombinedTable') I need to use to populate a table in an MS Word template. The table has 7 columns so I attempted the following using docxtpl module:

```
context = {
    'tpl_modules1': CombinedTable[0]
    'tpl_modules2': CombinedTable[2]
    'tpl_modules3': CombinedTable[4]
    'tpl_modules4': CombinedTable[6]
    'tpl_modules5': CombinedTable[8]
    'tpl_modules6': CombinedTable[10]
    'tpl_modules7': CombinedTable[12]
}
tpl.render(context)

tpl.save(FilePath + FileName)
```

Not the most elegant solution I know but am just trying to get this working- unfortunately *using this code with the following template results in tpl_modules7 data being written in to all columns, rather than just the 7th.*

[image: Image of word template]

Does anyone have advice for how to resolve this? I attempted to create a for loop through the columns as well as rows but was unsuccessful in writing anything to the doc (was saved as a blank & empty doc).

The CombinedTable variable is a list of 12 lists (one for each column in template, although only 7 contain data). Each of these 12 lists contains another list with cell data whose length is equal to the number of rows to be written to the table in that column. This means that the number of rows that are written to varies for each column.

EDIT: Looking more closely at the [docs](https://docxtpl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), it states that I cannot use `%tr` multiple times in the same row. I assume I will then have to use a loop through `%tc` and `%tr` (which I tried & couldn't get working). Any advice on how to implement this? Especially on the side of the word document. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this satisfactorily for my requirements, however my solution may not suit all. I simply set up 7 different tables in a document with 7 columns and adjusted margins/borders to suit the dimensions I required for the tables. Each of the 7 tables had identical docxtpl syntax as image in my question with the small buffer columns between them being replaced by columns in the word document.